# c++ calling a class function/data from a non-member

Tags: c++, sqlite

i am currently making a simple sqlite3 wrapper base on this tutorial ( http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm )

my problem is about the callback function in querying.

```
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
  int i;
  fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", (const char*)data);
  for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
    printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

callback function is not a member function of a class

```
class Wrapper() {
  public:
    Wrapper();
    ~Wrapper();
  private:
    vector<map<string, string> > result;
};
static int callback(){
  result.insert( ...data... );
}
```

how will i do go around with this. help is very much appreciated.
thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Use the `data` argument to pass a pointer to a class object.

```
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
  Wrapper * wrapper = static_cast<Wrapper*>(data);
  wrapper->result.insert( ...data... );
}
```

passing a suitable pointer to the sqlite function that uses the callback

```
Wrapper my_wrapper;
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, &my_wrapper, &err_msg);
```

Note that the callback will have to be a friend or static member to access `result` directly, as the example does. It can be a non-member if it only uses the public interface.

Comment: this part
`Wrapper * wrapper = static_cast<Wrapper>(data);`
gives an error
`no matching function for call to ‘Wrapper::Wrapper(void*&)`

and i dont get this part
`Wrapper my_wrapper;`
but the parameter is
`&myWrapper,`

Comment: @xeroblast: Sorry, those were typos. Cast the pointer to `Wrapper*` not `Wrapper`, and use the same name for the variable in both places.